# Get the corners of the plane surface 2D mesh

Tags: python, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh, open3d

I have a mesh as in the picture (In Red Color). I want to get the corners of the mesh so that I can recreate a plane at the exact positions without having to rely on the mesh. The mesh will always be approximately planar and rectangular because of the nature of the geometry. The normal of the plane can be oriented in the arbitrary directions (so using Bounding box is generally out), in general. Any algorithm I can use for this?[image: Mesh]

The mesh was created from the point cloud using Open3D library. The code for generating the mesh that I used is as follows, in case the context is needed:

```
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(segments[wall_segments[0]], depth=8, width=0, scale = 1.1, linear_fit=True)[0]
bbox = segments[wall_segments[0]].get_axis_aligned_bounding_box()
mesh = mesh.crop(bbox)
mesh = mesh.simplify_quadric_decimation(1000)
```